# Bayeuxclient disconnects

Tags: .net, websocket, long-polling, cometd, bayeux

I'm implementing Bayeuxclient(long-polling) for cometD connections for asynchronous messaging. Intermittently I receive a disconnect message out of the blue ( I haven't found any exception either in server or application logs) and try reconnecting. I believe some unknown latency is causing the issue (I'm not 100% sure).

Can you please suggest how I can workaround the issue ? By moving from long-polling to websockets can we have better performance ?

Comment: could you add more details to your question like code examples (even better if you upload it to github or somewhere else)

Comment: You are welcome to open an issue for discussion at the [CometD project](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues), home of the Bayeux protocol, as typically StackOverflow is not the right place for these troubleshooting issues.